# What are all of the non-solo types in Pokemon games?

Tags: pokemon-series

In the Pokemon games that I have played (R/B/Y, G/S/C, R/S/E), I recall that there are some types that never go alone

For example, there is no pure Flying type Pokemon, there would at least be Normal associated to them

The question is: what are all of the Pokemon types that require dual typing?

Comment: A quick look on Bulbapedia shows that there are 4 pure Flying Pokémon: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Flying_(type)#Pure_Flying-type_Pok.C3.A9mon

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of today there are no non-solo types left.

- In Gen 1 (Red/Blue/Yellow) there were four: Flying, Rock, Ice and Ghost.
- In Gen 2 (Gold/Silver) we got the first pure Ghost type in Misdreavus and the first pure Rock type in Sudowoodo. But the newly introduced Steel type wasn't used alone.
- Gen 3 (Ruby/Sapphire) introduced two pure Steel types, Mawile and Registeel, as well as three pure Ice types in Snorunt, Glalie and Regice.
- Gen 5 (Black/White) had the legendary Tornadus, which is pure Flying type.
- Gen 8 (Sword/Shield) the first non-legendary pure Flying type got introduced (Rookidee and its evolution Corvisquire).

Gen 4 has the promo legendary Arceus and Gen 7 the legendary Silvally both of which can be every single type depending on the carried item. Both are Normal type when not carrying an item.

The Dark and Fairy types had pure specimens from their inception.